# Manually insert values in an exported Realm file using Realm Browser

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to manually insert/type the values inside a realm database using a realm browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Go open your database file with the Realm Browser and, while selecting a row, you can double click a value (for strings and number types) or click the checkbox (for boolean types) in order to edit them. Also, if you have any one-to-one or one-to-many relationship on your model, a click on the property value will address you to explore the related object(s).

With the rows selected you can go to **Edit > Add new object** or type `⌘ +` for inserting a new row.

**EDIT:** From the application menu open **File > Import From** for importing a database using a CSV or XSLX file.